# Coupled reaction diffusion equation ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

How would one go about solving this with the B.C.s considering the derivatives are not defined at the boundary?[image]

Comment: There is still a one sided derivative at the boundary, which by assumption of the problem is well defined.

Comment: i mean there's 'zero influx' but the equations are interested in the divergence of influx which is not necessarily 0

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Maybe you're worried about edge cases in the whole class of mathematical functions can could be defined on the range $[0,L]$, but this does look like a thermodynamics problem, and the actual physically realistic solutions aren't going to be crazy on the boundary. You can assume they are $C^\infty$ continuous on $[0,L]$, not just $(0,L)$.

Comment: if  v is zero  is the derivative of v zero?

Comment: $v$ appears to be a constant parameter, so I'm not sure what you mean by the derivative of $v$. If $v$ is zero, then the BC is that both $P$ and $Q$ are locally constant at the boundaries.

Comment: i mean in general

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to solve
\begin{align}
\label{eq:1}
D\partial_x^2P+(\partial_x D-v)\partial_x P-\tau P&=S(x)\\
D\partial_x^2Q+(\partial_x D+v)\partial_x Q+\tau P&=0\\
\end{align}
subject to
\begin{align}
D\partial_x P-vP\Big|_{x=0}&=0\\
D\partial_x Q-vQ\Big|_{x=0}&=0\\
P(x=L)&=c\\
Q(x=L)&=c
\end{align}
The first equation shows two coupled linear 2nd order differential equation with variable coefficients.
To solve this system of equations, write $u=\partial_x P$ and $v=\partial_x Q$ (see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573788/two-coupled-second-order-differential-equations)), which will take it to four coupled first order differential equations (again, linear, nonhomogenous, and with variable coefficients).
You can then write this as
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v \\
P \\
Q
\end{pmatrix}'
=A 
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v \\
P \\
Q
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
S(x) \\
0 \\
S(x) \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
with $A$ some $4\times4$ matrix that you need to determine. To solve this last equation, have a look at [link](https://math24.net/linear-nonhomogeneous-systems-differential-equations-constant-coefficients.html).